# Snap to a rotating grid in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, rotation

I'm trying to made a thing where I can snap an object to a grid. Currently I have this code

```
float x = Mathf.Round(selected.position.x / gridScale) * gridScale;
float y = Mathf.Round(selected.position.y / gridScale) * gridScale;
Vector3 gridPos = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
```

but it doesn't work because the base of the grid rotates, which causes the snapped position to be offset. How do I make it so it can snap to the grid correctlty when it rotates?

Comment: Would it be an option to make this object a child of the rotating object? This way you would snap to the grid in local space but any rotations and also parent object translation would be automatically applied to the children as well ;)

Comment: No, maybe I failed to clarify clearly but the issue is when creating the object, once it is created it rotates fine, but trying to snap it onto the grid when the grid is rotated

Comment: As said: if it is a child of the grid it doesn't matter .. calculate the position in **local space** so the delta to the parent object in the parents coordinate space ... you don't have to care about any rotations at all ;)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to make the object a child of the grid. That way, the object is going to rotate with the grid.

[image]

However, sometimes that's not a possibility. In those cases, you can add a component called a Position Constraint to your object.

[image]

Your object will follow the Transform you put in the source.

If you want the object to stay in a specific position on the grid when it rotates, you can add an empty GameObject to the grid, and then add that object as a source to your object's Position Constraint.

[image]
[image]

If you want the object's rotation to match the grid's, you can also add a Rotation Constrains which functions similarly, but at that point you really have to wonder why you're not just making the object a child of the parent.